# Google API client secrets error (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api-python-client

I want to retrieve data from Google analytics. I have created a service account in the console and I am using Google's Python (`hello_analytics_api_v3.py`) code to access the data.

I have copied the `client_secrets.json` into my folder but get this error:

```
*SystemExit: 
WARNING: Please configure OAuth 2.0
To make this sample run you will need to populate the client_secrets.json file
found at:*
```

What should I do? I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: Just to double-check, have you added your own information to `client_secrets.json`, specifically the `client_id` and `client_secret`?

Comment: Also, where did you get the file `hello_analytics_api_v3.py` for those of us who aren't familiar (most people).

Comment: The * at the end of this string is a little weird:

      "To make this sample run you will need to populate the client_secrets.json file found at:*"

 
That's supposed to be the directory name where it it looking for the client_secrets.json file. "*" isn't going to work.

Comment: The downloaded client_secrets.json has details already.

Comment: I got the hello_analytics_api_v3 from Google Code

Comment: I put the * there, ignore that for now

Comment: Can you provide a link? And also provide the modifications you've made as code snippets?

Answer (score 12):

Ensure the terminal is pointing to the same path directory as your `client_secrets.json` file.

i.e. type `pwd` in the console you're using to call the script and the output should match the directory of where `client_secrets.json` is stored.

Comment: I accidentally had my file named "client_secret.json" (I missed the s).  The simple things will get you.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I was having this exact issue and deleted the credentials to my project and  creating new ones using the 'OAuth client ID' option. Follow step one of this page closley https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/installed-py

I also found a syntax error in the sample code provided by google 
The Lines:

```
print 'View (Profile): %s' % results.get('profileInfo').get('profileName')
print 'Total Sessions: %s' % results.get('rows')[0][0]
```

Should read:

```
print ('View (Profile): %s' % (results.get('profileInfo').get('profileName')))
print ('Total Sessions: %s' % (results.get('rows')[0][0]))
```

At least this solved it for me. Also, make sure the client_secrets.json is in the same directory as your python script.

Answer (score 2):

In the sample code at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video the call to `flow_from_clientsecrets()` passes `CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE` as a relative path.

To fix it, force the `CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE` argument to be an absolute path:

```
def get_authenticated_service(args):
  flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(
    os.path.abspath(os.path.join( 
      os.path.dirname(__file__),CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE)),
    scope=YOUTUBE_UPLOAD_SCOPE,
    message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I received this error because I still had the square brackets inside the client_id and client_secret.  It should just be the string with no brackets.

Comment: Thanks! This was the problem for me as well!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows system, follow this steps:

1. Put your file (`client_secrets.json`) in the directory (C:) or (D:).
2. In your Python file define your variable like this: 
   `CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "\client_secrets.json"`. Python will search the json file in the root C: or D: and will find it.

I had same problem with Google API for youtube and I solved it like that.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this error while using SimpleGmail for reading my mails.

I had added `client_secret.json` file in root directory of script.
I also tried passing absolute path in

```
gmail_client = Gmail(client_secret_file=secret_file)
```

After focussing on error properly, I found this error.

```
    /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py:255: UserWarning: Cannot access gmail_token.json: No such file or directory
      warnings.warn(_MISSING_FILE_MESSAGE.format(filename))
    Traceback (most recent call last): 
...
...
```

Check what kind of Application type you are using,
[image]

In my case, I had to use `Desktop App`