# Google API client_secrets error

Tags: python, pandas, google-analytics, google-api

I just installed Anaconda (with Python 3 as default), as I need it for pandas/accessing Google Analytics. Here is some info about accessing GA through Python & pandas: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/remote_data.html#remote-data-ga

A similar question was asked here [Google API client secrets error (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858927/google-api-client-secrets-error-python) but the answer does not seem helpful in my particular case. Namely, the error I have is different; I've placed the client_secrets.json file in the appropriate directory; the file is not empty and has the exact same contents as shown in the developer console.

Here is the code and error:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.ga as ga
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

df = ga.read_ga(metrics='sessions', dimensions='date', start_date='2015-07-01')

An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit:
WARNING: Please configure OAuth 2.0

You need to populate the client_secrets.json file found at:

/Users/usernamehere/anaconda/envs/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/client_secrets.json

with information from the APIs Console <https://code.google.com/apis/console>.
```

Some extra details about the setup:

- Besides Anaconda, I've also installed the [Google API library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation) and [GFlags](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-gflags)
- It appears GFlags is not compatible with Python 3, so I created a new environment using [the `conda create` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405561/how-to-install-2-anacondas-python-2-7-and-3-4-on-mac-os-10-9)
- The Google account used to access the [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project) has two-factor auth enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Google Developer Console used to provide default URI redirects, but not anymore.

When setting up client secrets, make sure to add the following to "Authorized redirect URIs":

`http://localhost:8080/`

This has to be exact--even a missing `/` will cause errors. One way to check this is to make sure the client_secrets.json file has this line:

`"redirect_uris":["http://localhost:8080/"]`

Comment: I don't know why but the client_secrets.json has this missing so  I added it to make it work.